# Relaxing the requirement in the definition of locally convex space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Among the several definitions of **locally convex spaces**, one is stated as below:

Let $X$ be a topological vector space. If for any $x\in X$ and for every open set $U$ containing $x$, **there is an open convex, absorbing and balanced set containing $x$ and contained in $U$**, then $X$ is called *locally convex*.

Can we change the definition to the following alternatives?

1. there is a convex, absorbing and balanced set containing $x$ and contained in $U$. (openness is deleted)
2. there is a convex set containing $x$ and contained in $U$ (openness and being absorbing and balanced are all deleted)

Comment: You'd definitely need to refine the second version, since $\{x\}$ itself, etc., satisfy the requirement...

Comment: This definition of locally convex TVS is not correct. Every non-empty balanced set contains $0$, but in a Hausdorff TVS every $x\neq 0$ has a neighborhood that does not contain $0$, so it cannot contain a balanced set.

Comment: @MaoWao I see. How if I edit the "balanced set" to "balanced set center in $x$" in three definition (standard, and two alternative)? I have already known that second definition still cannot be correct due to paul's comment.

Comment: @paulgarrett Oh thanks! Is the first alternative correct?

Comment: There is some subtlety about "absorbing" sets... Certainly open nbds of $0$ are absorbing, but I cannot easily give an example or counter-example about non-open absorbing sets. (With or without other adjectives, which are more elementary, in a locally convex context.) That is, a "barreled space" (or "kegly") is one in which every absorbing... set containing $0$ is open. Possibly Wikipedia gives counter-examples.